# Crear un endpoint y habilitar acceso

Tags: wordpress, api, postman, endpoint

Tengo un problema con el acceso a un endpoint. Os cuento.

He creado un endpoint personalizado de esta manera, siguiendo unos tutoriales:

```php
<?php

class Aviva extends WP_REST_Controller {

  //The namespace and version for the REST SERVER
  var $my_namespace = 'API/v';
  var $my_version   = '1';

  public function register_routes() {
    $namespace = $this->my_namespace . $this->my_version;
    $base      = 'endpoint';
    register_rest_route( $namespace, '/' . $base, array(
        'methods'         => 'GET',
        'callback'        => array( $this, 'get_data' ),
        'permission_callback'   => array( $this, 'get_permission' )
    )  );
  }

  // Register our REST Server
  public function hook_rest_server(){
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( $this, 'register_routes' ) );
  }

  public function get_permission (){

      return true;
      //return current_user_can( 'edit_something' );
  }

  public function get_data($request){

      $oId = $request->get_param( 'idSms' );
      $date = $request->get_param( 'date' );
      $state = $request->get_param( 'state' );

      $dbhost = 'localhost';
      $dbuser = 'user';
      $dbpass = 'pass';
      $dbname = 'dbname';
      $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);


      $sql = "INSERT INTO table (oId, state, date) values('" . $oId . "','" . $state . "','" . $date . "')";

      mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

      mysqli_close($conn);
  } 
}

$aviva = new Aviva();
$aviva ->hook_rest_server();
```

El endpoint se crea bien, pero no puedo acceder a él. Estoy usando Postman para hacer un GET y me devuelve siempre el siguiente error:

```
{
    "code": "rest_cannot_access",
    "message": "Sólo los usuarios autentificados pueden acceder a la REST API.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

He probado varios plugins para dar permisos de autenticación a la REST API, pero no funciona ninguno, o al menos no he sabido hacerlo.

Lo único que necesito es que se pueda acceder al endpoint de forma segura para dejar unos datos en formato JSON que guardaré en la base de datos para su posterior tratamiento.

Estoy bastante verde con este tema y agradacería cualquier ayuda. Llevo varios días con esto y me estoy volviendo loco, a ver si alguien puede echarme una mano.

Muchas gracias